# How to call a javascript type="module" from a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

[Wandering down a bit on MDN](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/) and [on WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-type), I saw that `type="module"` allows loading javascript modules on a webpage. But **how do you execute the code defined in the module?**

I have this module:

```
console.log('Starting module 1');

function addLiElement(text) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.classList.add('js-module-2');
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));

    document.querySelector('.output').appendChild(li);
}

console.log('End of module 1');

export default addLiElement;
```

The script is loaded in the webpage using `<script type="module" src="module.js"></script>` in `<head>`.

Now, if I call this classic javascript (in a `<script src="mysqcript.js"></script>`):

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    addLiElement('Hello, I am a basic code.js');
});
```

Then Firefox says that the `addLiElement` function does not exist. If I use `import {addLiElement} from "module-1.js";`, then Firefox says that `import` can only be used inside modules. And the module's `console.log` do not appear inside the console.

So, Can we link normal javascript to modules? If so, how?

Comment: See https://github.com/ModuleLoader/browser-es-module-loader for a way to do it

Comment: @Teemu FIrefox does support import/export (hence the `import cannot be used outside module`), but I didn't get how to use them to call the module's code from page's code

Comment: Reading the accepted answer in the linked dup says, that the __syntax__ is supported, but the modules are not loaded ("_What isn't supported is module loading..._")

Comment: @Teemu Okay, I understood "loading" as "being imported in the JS code" while it apparently means "not parsed at all" (because console.log and such inside module do nothing). Thanks !

Comment: They also say, that imported scripts are really working in MS Edge, have you tested?

Comment: @Teemu No, because I have no Edge for now anywhere :\ (it's more for the curiosity than for targeting production)